# Wrong display resolution after failed NVIDIA driver update

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution

Made the mistake of trying to manually update my Nvidia driver on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS.
Anyways the update failed and now I am left with a screen resolution that is wrong(too low resolution).
How do I restore the proper resolution? The attached shows I am still running the older 384 driver.

And this is my xorg file:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 378.13  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-05)  Tue Feb  7 19:37:00 PST
2017


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Coolbits" "4"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

[image: Software&Updates_Additional Drivers]

Comment: Please post the output of `xrandr`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the nVidia drivers and that will restore the open source nouveau drivers and the config your system was previously in (before the installation):

Launch a terminal and run:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`

or respond to my comment above and post the output of `xrandr` and we can show you how to change the resolution over the command line.

Comment: xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*

Comment: Thanks. Just want to confirm. Prior to making this mistake with a manual install I ALWAYS used Software & Updates to do any driver updates. I also recall that I ALWAYS had issues with the nouveau driver and stuck with the NVIDIA Binary driver as in my attached screen shot. 384.90 was last working version for me.

Comment: Is there a default 'uninstall' command or should there be an uninstall option if I try and run the above installer again?

Comment: Just use this and restart your computer: `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*` BTW, you can also try selecting a different version of the NVIDIA driver before running the command I suggested.

Comment: Thanks. Back in action. Only remaining issue is that I have lost my custom fan settings in NVIDIA XServer software. Don't recall if this has something to do with Coolbits or??

Comment: Try this [link](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/789888/set-fan-speed-without-an-x-server-solved-/?offset=3) - "Set fan speed without an X server" - please accept answer and vote up if this answer helped you.

Comment: xrandr is not supported by nvidia.  Some versions, you can get existing resolutions, but cannot addmode, so otherwise useless.  What is needed, is "how to" set a custom resolution that doesn't make the system unbootable.